# Sci-fi anthology about future crime

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, william-gibson

I remember reading an anthology collecting stories about crime, possibly crime-solving specifically. What I can remember about the book is:

1. General theme was crime/crime solving
2. Different authors for each story, one of which was William Gibson
3. One story was a murder mystery that hinged on phone-booth sized teleportation boxes in a network that spanned the globe
4. In one story the detectives use pictures of celebrities instead of police sketches when interviewing witnesses, but the pictures they have was sorely outdated (picture was of Harvey Keitel, which none of the characters seemed to recognize
5. I read it sometime in the mid to late 90's

Comment: The celebrity database sounds like the "separated at birth" program from William Gibson's "Virtual Light", but it is a novel, not a short story. As described here: [link](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1669). "_Separated at Birth was a police program you used in missing persons cases. You scanned a photo of the person you wanted, got back the names of half a dozen celebrities who looked vaguely like the subject_"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would guess the story about murder and teleportation booths is [A Kind of Murder](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50966) by Larry Niven. They are called *displacement booths*:

> The displacement booths had come suddenly. One year, a science fiction writer's daydream. The next, A.D. 1992, an experimental reality. Teleportation. Instantaneous travel. Another year and they were being used for cargo transport. Two more, and the passenger displacement booths were springing up everywhere in the world.

Looking at the publication history I see this was published in the anthology [Cyber-Killers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?8490), and that also featured the Gibson story Johnny Mnemonic so I would guess this is the anthology you remember. It was published in 1998 so it matches your time frame.

[image: Cyber-Killers]

I cannot track down a copy so I cannot confirm the story that mentions Harvey Keitel. [It is on Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Cyber_killers/qDtyNgAACAAJ?hl=en) but unfortunately not in a searchable form.

Comment: Yes, the cover rings a bell, and reading a synopsis of the Niven story that includes the ending confirms that's the right short story at least. Good find!

Comment: I have a copy here — but after a flick through, I didn't spot anything related to the Harvey Keitel memory.  (I must have read it decades ago, and although I remember quite a few of the stories — some real classics there! — the rest is a blank I'm afraid.)  Let me know if there's anything specific I can check for you.